# Can i use jquery to call an ajax function above my website public directory?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have been trying to set up a basic website login system. And right now i am stuck on error validation prior to sending credentials to the database. My problems are: my naive understanding of website architecture & my lack of proficiency in AJAX and JQuery. I will try and make my question as concise as possible, but i guarantee somewhere in here i'll ask a stupid question :S.

### My Scope:

I am trying to set up a very simple web front end that interacts with my pre-existing SQL backend. I am also trying to have much of my interaction with my backend separate from my public_html file. Thus obfuscating all of the really vital stuff(DB credentials, SQL interactions etc.). This making it incredibly difficult for nefarious individuals to damage my backend framework. I suppose you could say i'm going for web "security" by making almost all of my files(except 2, login.php and loggedIn.php) completely unreadable by anyone who is not directly able to access the server.

**For instance**

My web directory:

```
secrets
public_html
-MyWebsite
```

**IF:**

I place my login.php, my Jquery.js, and my Ajax.php file ALL into the "public_html/MyWebsite" it works fine.

My web directory:

```
secrets
public_html
I
-MyWebsite
I
--login.php
--Jquery.js
--Ajax.php
```

**BUT**

If i change the placement of the files things begin to break down. I am imagining this is due to something in my code that i just cant seem to see. Again probably a super naive error in my architecture / logic?

This is the architecture i am trying to achieve:

```
secrets
I
--Jquery1.js
--Ajax.php
*************
public_html
I
-MyWebsite
I
--login.php    (with a few Jquery/Ajax calls)
--loggedIn.php ( interspersed referencing my core files ^)
--Jquery.js
```

The reason i am trying to achieve this is because in practice if we have these 2 live on the web. if we navigate to:

www.MyWebsite.com/MyWebsite/login.php

**Case 1 & 2 from above ^**
 will both bring us to login.php

However if we type in:

www.MyWebsite.com/MyWebsite/Jquery.js

**Case 1** 
 Will bring us to Jquery.js in plain text. 100% visible to literally anyone who wants to just check it out.

**Case 2**
 Will bring us to a 404. Problem solved, all JQuery is invisible to the world.

The same applies to AJAX however AJAX will only ever yield the result of the call. so not AS detrimental to web security but still kind of a bummer?

So. As it stands right now Case 1 works fine for me but i cannot figure out why case 2 will not. Again, please forgive me if that is a really stupid I'm clearly not a "pro" per se. But i will try and provide as much cleaned up code as possible to make this as straightforward as i can with very little understanding of web architecture :S.

**CASE 1 CODE**

*login.php*

```
<?php

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- load our javascript file -->

    <title>Login</title>

</head>
<body onload="formBuild()">

</body>
</html>
```

*Jquery.js*

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $('#logForm').submit(function(event)
        {
            $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); 
            $('.help-block').remove(); 

            var logData = {

                'userName': $('input[name=txtUserName]').val()
            }

            $.ajax({
                type        : 'POST', //Form Type
                url         : 'Ajax.php', 
                data        : logData, 
                dataType    : 'json', // Return Expectation,

                encode      : true
            })

            .done(function(data)
                {
                    if(!data.success)
                    {
                       if (data.errors.userName) 
                            {
                                $('#userName-group').addClass('has-error'); 
                                $('#userName-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.userName+ '</div>'); 
                            }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //INITIATE DO DATABASE STUFF
                    }
                })
            .fail(function(data)
                {

                });
            event.preventDefault();
        });

});



function formBuild() {


$('body').append('<div class="container" id="MainBody"></div>');
$("#MainBody").append('<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="logForm" name="" method="POST" action=""></form>');
$("#logForm").append('<div id="userName-group" class="form-group"</div>');
$("#userName-group").append('<label for="txtUserName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username:</label>');
$("#logForm").append('<div class="form-group" id="btnSubby"></div>');
$("#btnSubby").append('<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button></div>');
$("#MainBody").append('<div class="form-group" id="btnNeggy"></div>');
$("#MainBody").append('<div class="container text-right "><button  class="btn btn-warning" onclick="checkError()">Help Me<span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button></div>');
}

function checkError() 
{
  //TEST FLAG TO SEE IF AJAX AND JQUERY ARE TALKING 
   $("#logForm").hide(); 
}
```

*Ajax.php*

```
<?php

$inputUser= $_POST['userName'];

if (empty($inputUser))
    {
        $errors['userName'] = 'Username is required';
    }


if (!empty($inputUser))
        {
            $errors['userName'] = 'You have to enter a Username';
        }



if (!empty($errors)) 
    {
        //RETURN ERROR DATA
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['errors']  = $errors;
        $_SESSION['Fail'] = "True";
    } 
else
    {
        //ALL ERRORS PASSED
        //DO DB STUFF
    }

//Return Data to form. - Errors
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

This results in my login page being populated with a username text field and a submit button, as well as a help me button for testing purposes.

When i submit the form i have the error data show up below the fields and everything works as it should. I cleared out some of the useless code that had no effect on the system from above ^ so if there is a bracket or semicolon missing somewhere i can guarantee you that is not the problem. Because i can see it working in front of me. Its got to be something in the syntax or something? Or again, my ignorance as to "How a website directory transmits information".

**CODE FOR CASE 2**

*login.php*

```
<?php


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Jquery1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

    <title>Login</title>

</head>
<body onload="populatePage()">
</body>
</html>
```

*Jquery.js*

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 { 

});

function formBuild() {
$('body').append('<div class="container" id="MainBody"></div>');
$("#MainBody").append('<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="logForm" name="" method="POST" action=""></form>');
$("#logForm").append('<div id="userName-group" class="form-group"</div>');
$("#userName-group").append('<label for="txtUserName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username:</label>');
$("#logForm").append('<div class="form-group" id="btnSubby"></div>');
$("#btnSubby").append('<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button></div>');
$("#MainBody").append('<div class="form-group" id="btnNeggy"></div>');
$("#MainBody").append('<div class="container text-right "><button  class="btn btn-warning" onclick="checkError()">Help Me<span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button></div>');
}

function checkError() 
{
    // CALL JQuery FILE FROM OUTSIDE WEB  DIRECTORY*******
    $.ajax({url: "config/Jquery1.js", dataType: "script", success: function(TestLogin){}});
    //*******PROBABLY WHERE THINGS ARE GOING WRONG?******
}
```

*Ajax.php*

```
<?php

function Login()
{
    $inputUser = $_POST['userName'];

   if (!empty($inputUser))
        {

        }
    else
        {
            $errors['userName'] = 'Username is required';
        }

    if (!empty($errors)) 
    {
        //RETURN ERROR DATA
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['errors']  = $errors;
        $_SESSION['Fail'] = "True";
    } 
}

//RETURN VABIABLE DECLARATION
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

*Jquery1.js*

```
function TestLogin()
{
    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); 
    $('.help-block').remove(); 

    var logData = {
        'userName': $('input[name=txtUserName]').val()
    }

    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', //Form Type
        url         : 'Ajax.php', 
        data        : logData, 
        dataType    : 'json', // Return Expectation,
        encode      : true,
        success     : function(Login){
            //SUCCEED AND MESS WITH DB
            //IT NEVER SEEMS TO MAKE IT HERE?
        }
    })

    .done(function(data)
        {
            if(!data.success)
            {
               if (data.errors.userName) 
                    {
                        $('#userName-group').addClass('has-error'); 
                        $('#userName-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.userName+ '</div>');
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                //FAILURE CONDITIONS
            }
        })
    .fail(function(data)
        {

        });
    event.preventDefault();
}


function checkError() 
{
   //AGAIN, TEST BUTTON TO HIDE FORM AND SEE IF COMMUNICATION IS TAKING PLACE
   $("#logForm").hide(); 
}
```

Case 1 seems to work perfectly fine. I am able to test the input data and display the error messages beneath if something is wrong. And if it passes i can send the user to loggedin.php.

In Case 2 the form creates itself fine, and is working? However nothing happens when i click either the submit or the help me button(little test button)? So somewhere between Jquery.js and Jquery1.js communication is breaking down?

After writing this i'm beginning to think that the problem lies in AJAX being outside of the public_html? I remember reading somewhere that it has to be in the same directory as the file calling it? I wasn't sure and this is why i am here. Wondering if anyone has an opinion on what i am doing wrong (either syntactically or logically?). But i really just want to find a way to obfuscate my code from End Users while still having the capacity for them to view and interact with all the data being stored on my database once my system verifies them?

Should i have the Ajax.php file in the root directory? Am i able to have AJAX/Jquery files OUTSIDE of the web root? In order to attain obfuscation? Can i store all of my files except my login.php in my secrets file to keep everything locked away? Which files can i do that with? Which can i not? Is there a tutorial/preferred reading you know of that may help me on my journey to build a website using AJAX, JQuery, HTML, XML etc?

Sorry i have so many questions. This has just been racking my brain for a while now. I believe there may be a syntax error or 2 in here? I just copied over most of my web front end, and then deleted other features from the code that had nothing to do with this problem. Trying to keep it clean.

So there may be a missing bracket, semicolon etc. But i guess my question lies more in the fundamental understanding of the HTML web directory system. I run my DB files from the secrets file currently and interact with the Database just fine. Am i able to store my JQuery there as well if i call it from somewhere else and load the file with AJAX? Can i store all of my JQuery and AJAX code inside of /Secrets along with my DB configuration etc?

Sorry for the novel of a question. I apologize if this is hard on the eyes anywhere. I tried to make it as cleaned up as possible.

If anyone knows of any way i might be able to achieve my desired goal of running JQuery, and AJAX from outside the web root. Or could tell me why that is impossible and maybe where to put my files for best (possible) security as far as my files go. It would be greatly appreciated. Thank you all very much for your time!

**TL;DR:**
2 cases above ^. each have their own respective web directory setup.
Case 1 works. Case 2 doesn't.
Can you find the reason Case 2 doesn't?

Comment: First, please read about how to create a [mcve], emphasis on “Minimal.” There is a *huge* amount of unnecessary information in this question. Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn’t this code working?**”) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Second, no, you can’t use AJAX to call something that’s not web-accessible, for good reason. Imagine if you could; you could hack any website with no effort. You must make your AJAX endpoint accessible to the user; AJAX doesn’t do any magic to get around the server’s restrictions on what directories and files it will serve.

Comment: @EdCottrell Thank you Ed! That is going to be a read of mine before my next post on here! Again, super not pro here. So i am going to ask a follow up stupid question. JQuery HAS to be inside public_html and AJAX CAN be inside my secrets folder?

Comment: No, *everything* you want to make directly accessible over the web needs to be in your server’s target folder. That includes your pages, images, scripts (including jQuery), and anything you want to call via AJAX. If you put something in a private, non-web-accessible folder, then you can’t access it directly over the web. It would be like trying to put a notice on your office door by locking the notice in a safe in the closet; it doesn’t work that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All js/css/images work in the client side (Except for node), means that it needs to be downloaded in order to work so it should live in the public_html folder since it needs to be retrieved by the end user browser in order to be executed.

Comment: excellent thank you so much! So JQuery cannot exist ouside of public_html?